# subgroup of direct product of two groups

Tags: group-theory

Its seems true but I did not see in any group theory book. Let $G\times_{c} H$ be product of two abelian groups (both are infinite). Then $I$ is subgroup of product iff $I = A\times_{c} B$ where $A$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $B$ is a subgroup of $H$. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not true: One has the diagonal embedding $G \to G \times G$ by $g \mapsto (g, g)$.

Comment: this is a nice example

Answer (score 2):

You can find very detailed information about  subgroups of direct product of groups (not necessarily Abelian) in:

Bauer K., Sen D., Zvengrowski P. A Generalized Goursat Lemma. http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.0024 (2011)